# checkboxlist selected items not gets select & inserts blank values in string

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a form in which data gets insert. There are some checkboxlist. CheckboxList binds with table in db. Now after selecting items it should enter selected values in db table but it inserts empty strings.

I have two checkboxlist (products, payment) Payment works fine. problem is in products.

VB code

```
Private Sub list_business_hospital_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.PopulateProducts()
    Me.PopulatePayments()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateProducts()
    productsList.Items.Clear()
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
            .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from chemistsProducts"
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    Dim item As New ListItem()
                    item.Text = sdr("productName").ToString()
                    item.Value = sdr("productName").ToString()
                    'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                    productsList.Items.Add(item)
                End While
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    productsList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", "All"))
End Sub

Private Sub PopulatePayments()
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
            .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from payment"
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    Dim item As New ListItem()
                    item.Text = sdr("paymentName").ToString()
                    item.Value = sdr("paymentID").ToString()
                    'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                    ListPayment.Items.Add(item)
                End While
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    ListPayment.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", "All"))
End Sub

Private Sub save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
        Dim selectedProducts As String = String.Empty
        For Each chk As ListItem In productsList.Items
            If chk.Selected = True Then
                selectedProducts &= "<li>" + chk.Text + "</li>"
            End If
        Next


        Dim payments As String = String.Empty
        For Each chk As ListItem In ListPayment.Items
            If chk.Selected = True Then
                payments &= "<li>" + chk.Text + "</li>"
            End If
        Next

        Try
            Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO chemists (`products`, `payment`) values ('" + selectedProducts + "', '" + payments + "')"

            Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str1
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            con.Open()
            str2 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
            Response.Redirect("business-added.aspx")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Here Payment gets inserted what I have selected. Problem is in selectedProducts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below in page load,

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Me.PopulateProducts()
    Me.PopulatePayments()
End If
```